Factoring a finite field polynomial known to have all irreducible quadratic factors.
Is there a faster method other than brute force search to find any factor of a finite field polynomial when it is known that all the factors are irreducible quadratics?
Example case: 
$GF(2^{16})$ modulo $x^{16} + x^{12} + x^3 + x + 1$
Polynomial with coefficients in $GF(2^{16})$ where the coefficients are only $0$ or $1$:
$x^{32} + x^{22} + x^2 + x + 1$
Since all 16 quadratic factors are irreducible, there are no roots.
All 16 irreducible quadratic factors in hex, found by brute force search:
$x^2 + 04c4 \ x + 118d$
$x^2 + 09ad \ x + 1cec$
$x^2 + 0e38 \ x + 1cb7$
$x^2 + 16b6 \ x + 1dbc$
$x^2 + 173b \ x + 0cf9$
$x^2 + 1c89 \ x + 1cf0$
$x^2 + 40ab \ x + 4be1$
$x^2 + 524f \ x + 0a76$
$x^2 + 5e62 \ x + 0716$
$x^2 + 5eec \ x + 0a37$
$x^2 + b67f \ x + 4188$
$x^2 + be6f \ x + fbf0$
$x^2 + e079 \ x + 17d4$
$x^2 + effe \ x + ed71$
$x^2 + f62b \ x + 07d5$
$x^2 + fd83 \ x + 17dd$
The polynomial $x^{32} + x^{22} + x^2 + x + 1$ with coefficients in $GF(2)$ is irreducible and primitive: $x$ is a primitive element. All 16 quadratic factors in $GF(2^{16})$ are also primitive. The purpose of this is to use sub-field | composite field | tower field mapping to speed up finding the multiplicative inverse of a number $1/x$ for the $GF(2)$ polynomial.

Your 16 factors seem to be polynomials over GF$(2^{16})$, not over GF$(2^{4})$ as you say, since the 4 hex digits  of each coefficient presumably represent an element of GF$(2^{16})$, which here is considered to be the set of polynomials of degree 15 or less in GF$(2)[x]$, with addition and multiplication modulo $x^{16}+x^{12}+x^3+x+1$.   I don't see where "GF$(2^4)$ modulo $x^{16}+x^{12}+x^3+x+1$" comes into it at all, or indeed what you mean by that phrase.

Assumed: You have read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields and have access to Knuth's Art of Computer Programming, vol. 2, ch. 4.6.2.

@DilipSarwate - thanks for catching that mistake, corrected now.  It is supposed to be $GF(2^{16})$.

@EricTowers - so far I've only found articles on how to factor polynomials for $GF(q)$ when $q$ is odd, such as $GF(3^9)$, and that is for cases where the degrees of the factors are unknown. There are also cases where some factors are linear, which have simple methods for finding the linear factors. In this case, it is known that all factors are quadratic and irreducible | primitive.

Undoubtedly you know that in a case like yours finding one factor gives the rest as they are all conjugate over the prime field (basically keep applying the Frobenius to the coefficients of one of the factors). Anyway, I am a bit optimistic about some variant of Cantor-Zassenhaus working here. Too bad, I'm not an expert on that (and I may be totally wrong). Thinking....

As predicted, C-Z in characteristic two is based on splitting according to the trace as opposed to quadratic residues.

@JyrkiLahtonen - thanks for finding this.
